# Being double the length and width of the image, why?

Tags: xamarin.android, android-bitmap

I have this code:

```
BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable)this.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.add1);
int height = bd.Bitmap.Height;
int width = bd.Bitmap.Width;
Toast.MakeText(this, width.ToString() + "  " + height.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
```

The width and height of add1.png is 55*55 pixels, but Toast showes 110 * 110 pixels, why?

Comment: Hi, I created a basic demo to test the code, the values of the width and height are correct. Did you test the code with other image files? For example, I test the functino with file of your profile, the result is 32*32. Please test it on your side to check that.

Comment: Hello and thank you. My profile image is 64*64 pixels and Toast shows 128*128 pixels. It doubles the length and width of each image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is caused by the resolution of the device. The value returned by bitmap.Width will be adjusted according to the different dpi, this dpi may be different for different models. If the device has a higher resolution, higher numbers may be printed here.

To get the original size of the image file, you need to divide the size by the dpi value.

```
var density = Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;

BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable)this.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.test);
var the_original_height = bd.Bitmap.Height / density;
var the_orignial_width = bd.Bitmap.Width / density;

Toast.MakeText(this, the_original_height.ToString() + "*" + the_original_height.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
```